# javascript not loading in express/node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am doing a small MEAN app

My javascript inside the html is not loading

below is my express route

```
app.get("/getuser/:id",userRoute.getUser);
```

**directory structure**
*nodejs/view*

****server file****

My Route Function

```
var getUser=function(req,res)
{
    console.log("hieieieiei");
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/view/index.html'));
};
```

My html file name is **index.html** and my js file name is **test.js** . Both are in folder named **view** .

I have this mentioned in my html . Can someone help

**index.html**

```
   <html>
<head lang="en">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> dfdfdfddddddddddddddddddd</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="clicker()"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
function clicker()
{
    alert("hi ");
}
```

Comment: do you get any error message?

Comment: please add more of your code

Comment: added some more code pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My html file name is index.html and my js file name is test.js . Both are in folder named view .

According to http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html you need to tell express which directory, or directories, you're serving your static files from using `express.static`.

So, you could try:

1. Create a public folder in your project
2. Move test.js from your views folder to the public folder created in step 1

Then update your configuration code so it includes the following:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Hopefully that'll do the trick.

Comment: thanks and where should my html go .. Can i retain it in the same place ...Thanks a lot again

Comment: @BalajiV It might depend: are you using a template engine such as Jade? or just static HTML?

Comment: I am using static html and i have java script inside that . I dont want to use any templating engines like jade